# componentDidUpdate doesn't update state with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

The goal of this app is to let met add an item in a `Flatlist` present in the List Item screen, using `React-Redux` and `React Navigation`. Basically I type name and category in the Create Item screen and send it in the form of an array to the List Item screen with React Navigation, and once I'm in the List Item screen I use `componentDidMount` to dispatch the action and update the state in the class compoment, the problem is that nothing shows up, even using the `console.log` it just gives me back the empty array present in the Redux Reducers screen.

**CREATE ITEM SCREEN**

```
export class item extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      category: '',
        };
  }



  submitItem = (name, category) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("ListItem", {
      itemList: {
    name: name,
    category: category,
   }});

  };


  

  render() {
    const { name, category } = this.state;
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header>
          <Left>
            <Button onPress={() =>
              this.submitItem(
                this.state.name,
                this.state.category,
              )
            }>
                <Text>Sumbit</Text>
            </Button>
```

**ITEM LIST SCREEN**

```
class ListItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      itemList:[],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount (props, state) {
    if (this.props.route.params?.itemList) {
      () => this.props.dispatch({type:'ADD_ITEM'});
    }
    return null;
  }
```

**REDUX REDUCER**

```
const initialState = {
  currentUser: null,
  itemList: [],
};

export const user = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type){
      case USER_STATE_CHANGE:
        return {
          ...state,
          currentUser: action.currentUser,
        };
      case 'ADD_ITEM': 
      return{
        itemList: state.itemList,
      }
      default:
        return state
  }
  
};
```

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` is not called for the initial render. Sounds like you would need to handle it in `componentDidMount` or perhaps both

Comment: You are right, I switched it with that, not it returns the error : `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.route')`, forgive me but I'm still learning to code

Comment: you probably need to use `this.props`

Comment: thanks, it doesn't return the error anymore, but now it just doesn't return anything

Answer (score 2):

I think when you are dispatching an action you are not adding the action.payload to the state.itemList.What I meant

```
const initialState = {
  currentUser: null,
  itemList: [],
};

export const user = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type){
      case USER_STATE_CHANGE:
        return {
          ...state,
          currentUser: action.currentUser,
        };
      case 'ADD_ITEM': 
      return{
        ...state,
        itemList: addItemToList(state.itemList,action.payload), //a util function to add items to the list. 
// And action.payload is the value ,which passed when you are dispatching the action 'ADD_ITEM'
      }
      default:
        return state
  }
  
};
```

And when you are dispatching the action it should be

```
componentDidMount (props, state) {
    if (this.props.route.params?.itemList) {
      () => this.props.dispatch({type:'ADD_ITEM',payload:this.props.route.params.itemList}); 
// passing the itemList to as the payload of the action.

    }
    return null;
  }
```

I guess this modification should suffice. More on React-Redux [here](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)

Comment: thank you, but it still just returns the empty array from the initial state in my Flatlist.

Comment: Try using selectors in your project and also don't forget to write lots of console.log for debugging. Let me know anything I can help. @Salvo

Comment: I wrote lots of console.log as you said, when I wrote one inside the ComponentDidMount it would return nothing in the terminal, so that's where I think the problem is.

Comment: It's as if componentDidMount doesn't work or won't receive anything, because even if I remove the dispatch function and write a simple console.log, nothing returns in the terminal

Comment: If the component did not mount, then somehow the component wasn't called. Where did you imported the ListItem class?

Comment: I’m using React-Navigation Stack.Screen to travel between screens and also to send the param itemList

Comment: In createItem screen , when you are pressing the button you are sending the state values as parameters in submitItem function , but the state parameters was declared initially as empty, thus when you are navigating to ListItem, basically two empty values passed down. I think that's why it's giving you empty value.

Comment: Now come to why the ListItem class component did not mount, as you can see React follows the unidirectional flow, what I meant by is, when a child component is mounted the parent component also mounted, but say you changed a state in the child component, the parent will not mount again, because it follows the unidirectional flow. So you gotta design your app carefully, which component will be children and which will be parents.

Comment: Thank you, yes I'm generally new to programming so I'm still learning, is there any other method that updates the component when a new state is brought to it?

Comment: Also, they are two children components, I used a `getDerivedStateFromProps`  before, but I didn't use Redux, and the page would re-render itself, but since I implemented Redux to share global states it just wouldn't work.

Comment: The simple solution would be , Merging these components. Merge Item and ItemList into one. When user clicks the button , you'll dispatch the action and with payload and the reducer will add the items to the itemlist. Also you can also save the items in the local state .